# Return List value from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, selecteditem

I have two windows, `windowA` that has a button to open `windowB`, and `windowB` has a button to close itself and also return List value. I tried this code, but the value keep null. `windowB` has RadGridView control, i want to get the selectedItem from it and add it on a list.

```
public class WindowA : Window
{
    ...

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowB winB = new WindowB();
        if (winB.ShowDialog() == false)
        {
            listClass lc = winB.SelectedItemButton;
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class WindowB : Window
{
 ...
    public listClass SelectedItemButton
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            selectedItem = ((listClass)AGridView.SelectedItem);
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

the results are a listClass, but has no value inside. Why? and how can i make `selectedItem = ((listClass)AGridView.SelectedItem);` this line works to another window?

Comment: You should explicitly set winB's **DialogResult** when close. By the way, selectedItem and SelectedItemButton in above code is **recursively referenced**, no need be that complex.

Comment: @LeiYang how did DialogResult works? i'm new in c#. yes i made the selectedItem in button_Click just to make sure if it works, but it isn't.

Comment: "winB.listClass" ? I don't see a property or a field named like that in the WindowB class.

Comment: @DotNeter ah yes, i edited it. thanks

Comment: As @LeiYang said, you have a cyclic call, I advice you to use property only to encapsulate fields since you're new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example for you:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 dlg = new Window1();
        if(dlg.ShowDialog()??false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dlg.S);
        }
    }
}

    // Dialog
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public string S
    {
        get
        {
            return this.txt1.Text;
        }
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create your listClass variable in Window1 and while you are opening the Window2 you should pass this variable as a parameter. Here is my demo:

First window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        testClass.Test = "Initial";

        Second second = new Second(testClass);
        second.ShowDialog();

        label.Content = testClass.Test; // It prints "Changed"
    }
}
```

Second window:

```
public partial class Second : Window
{
    TestClass testClass;

    public Second(TestClass sent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testClass = sent;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        testClass.Test = "Changed"; // Change the value
    }
}
```

My testClass (listClass):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```